# Prevent HTML5 Video native controls from appearing on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video embedded in a webpage. For various reason I do not have access to the video tag itself, though I can access it through an iFrame.  Via JavaScript, I have run the following code:

```
videoElement.removeAttribute('controls');
videoElement.muted = true;
```

where 'videoElement' is a reference to the DOM object of the video tag.

The video mutes, which means its responding to setting the 'mute' property, but the native controls still appear when the mouse hovers over the video, even though I have removed the 'controls' attribute.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I'm using, it uses the Kaltura platform, so might not make much sense:

```
<script src="http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/{PARTNER_ID}/sp/{PARTNER_ID}00/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/{uiConfId}/partner_id/{PARTNER_ID}"></script>

<script>
    mw.setConfig('Kaltura.LeadWithHTML5', true);
    mw.setConfig('EmbedPlayer.NativeControls', true);
    mw.setConfig('EmbedPlayer.EnableRightClick', false);
    mw.setConfig('controls', false);

    kWidget.embed({
            'targetId': 'kaltura_player_0000000000',
            'wid': '_000000',
            'uiconf_id': '000000',
            'entry_id': '1_000000',
            'flashvars': {
                'controlsHolder.includeInLayout': false,
                'controlsHolder.visible': false,
                'externalInterfaceDisabled': false,
                'loop': false,
                'autoPlay': true,
                'autoMute': true
            },
            'params': {
                'wmode': 'transparent'
            },
            readyCallback: function( playerId ){
                var kdp = $('#kaltura_player_0000000000_ifp').contents().find('video');

                // This is where I attempt to remove the controls attribute:

                kdp[0].removeAttribute('controls');
                kdp[0].muted = true;
            }
    });
</script>
```

This Kaltura library then creates an iFrame and populates it the appropriate media player for the user's device / browser, whether it's HTML5 video, Flash etc.  The drawback is that you lose a certain amount of control, and are limited to what Kaltura allows you to configure.

Comment: please post code, example, demo page, plug in used if any. we need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Ramy - I've added the code above, though it might not make much sense. At the moment I'm manually copying the markup that the above library is inserting in the page, which gives me a raw HTML5 video tag, over which I have complete control.  This allows me to remove "controls" attribute. Now I just have to manually create a fallback to the flash player for older browsers. I'll post my progress to this thread.

Comment: if changing the video player library is an option. give http://www.videojs.com/ a quick try to see if it helps. It doesn't create the video in an iframe and it's fully open source so you can host it in your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found it very hard to discover how to customise the look and feel of the Kaltura Media Player, took a long time of reading the docs and experimenting, but the following long-winded aproach is how I finally how I managed it:

---

I wrote a custom plugin for Kaltura, and then put my finctionality in that plugin:

```
kWidget.embed({
    'targetId': 'kaltura_player_0000000000',
    'wid': '_000000',
    'uiconf_id': 00000000,
    'flashvars': {
        'controlsHolder.includeInLayout': false,
        'controlsHolder.visible': false,
        'externalInterfaceDisabled': false,
        'loop': false,
        'autoPlay': true,
        'autoMute': true,
        'IframeCustomPluginCss1' : 'assets/css/custom_styles.css?sid=',
        "video-component": {
            'plugin': true,
            'iframeHTML5Js' : 'assets/js/custom_component.js?sid='
        },
        readyCallback: function(playerId) {
            var kdp = document.getElementById(playerId);

            kdp.addJsListener( 'playerStateChange', function(playerState, playerId) {
                if (['playing','paused'].indexOf(playerState) > -1) {
                    // declared in custom_component.js
                    updateStateButton();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The code above configures the basic player, then the plugin adds my custom controls and binds them to the player, and a custom css file hides the controls th eplayer ships with:

```
mw.kalturaPluginWrapper(function() {

    mw.PluginManager.add( 'video-component', mw.KBaseComponent.extend({

        defaultConfig: {
            parent: "videoHolder",          // the container for the button 
            order: 41,                      // the display order ( based on layout )
            displayImportance: 'low',       // the display importance, determines when the item is removed from DOM
            align: "right",                 // the alignment of the button

            cssClass: "kaltura-logo",       // the css name of the logo
            href: 'http://www.kaltura.com', // the link for the logo
            title: 'Kaltura',               // title
            img: null                       // image
        },
        getComponent: function() {
            console.log('running custom video component');

            if (!this.$el) {
                var playPauseBtn = document.createElement('img');
                playPauseBtn.setAttribute('id', 'play-pause');
                playPauseBtn.setAttribute('src', 'assets/images/pause.png');

                var muteButton = document.createElement('img');
                muteButton.setAttribute('id', 'video-volume');
                muteButton.setAttribute('src', 'assets/images/volume_on.png');

                this.$el = document.createElement('div');
                this.$el.setAttribute('id', 'custom-video-controls');
                this.$el.setAttribute('id', 'custom-video-controls');

                this.$el.appendChild(playPauseBtn);
                this.$el.appendChild(muteButton);

                var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
                var video = videos[0];

                var togglePlayPauseBtn = function(buttonClicked) {
                    // player state can be toggled via clicking on the video, or on the play / pause button
                    // if the play / pause button is clicked it will trigger the 'playerStateChange' event
                    // which will trigger this function again, the following statements prevent a race condition
                    if (window.buttonClicked) {
                        window.buttonClicked = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (buttonClicked) {
                        window.buttonClicked = true;
                    }

                    // togle video state
                    if (video.paused) {
                        video.play();
                        $(playPauseBtn).attr('src', 'assets/images/pause.png');
                    } else {
                        video.pause();
                        $(playPauseBtn).attr('src', 'assets/images/play.png');
                    }
                }

                window.parent.updateStateButton = function() {
                    togglePlayPauseBtn();
                }

                $(playPauseBtn).on('click', function() {
                    togglePlayPauseBtn(true);
                });

                $(muteButton).on('click', function() {
                    if (!video.muted) {
                        video.muted = true;
                        $(muteButton).attr('src', 'assets/images/volume_on.png');
                    } else {
                        video.muted = false;
                        $(muteButton).attr('src', 'assets/images/volume_off.png');
                    }
                });

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(playPauseBtn).fadeOut('slow');
                    $(muteButton).fadeOut('slow');
                }, 2000);

                $('.mwPlayerContainer').on('mousemove', function() {
                    clearInterval(window.playPauseFadeOut);

                    $(playPauseBtn).fadeIn(100);
                    $(muteButton).fadeIn(100);

                    window.playPauseFadeOut = setTimeout(function() {
                        $(playPauseBtn).fadeOut('slow');
                        $(muteButton).fadeOut('slow');
                    }, 1200);
                });
            }

            return $(this.$el);
        }
    }) );

});
```

Finally, here is the custom css:

```
.mwPlayerContainer .playerPoster, 
.mwPlayerContainer .largePlayBtn, 
.mwPlayerContainer .controlBarContainer,
.mwPlayerContainer .topBarContainer  {
    display: none !important;
}
.mwPlayerContainer .videoHolder #custom-video-controls {
    text-align: center;
}
.mwPlayerContainer .videoHolder #custom-video-controls #play-pause {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -80px 0 0 -80px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mwPlayerContainer .videoHolder #custom-video-controls #video-volume {
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 50px;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
videoElement.controls = false
```

Comment: From what I've read that won't work because the controls attribute is aboolean atribute, which means the browser only tests if is present or not, therefore it doesn't matter what the actual value of the attribute is , so long as it is present. Having said that, I haven't verified this on all browsers.

Comment: You can dynamically turn on/off the controls. See this example I've made where the controls are toggled every 2 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/4shrB/